# PFQuery adding data to tableview cells with for In Loops

Tags: swift, uitableview, parse-platform, for-in-loop

I have two versions of code. Version 1 is the code I intend on using. I am trying to look up a current user's friends' in the friend array. For every friend, I want to append certain items to each array to display in a tableview cell. Version 1 incorporates a for in loop with i friends array contains: ["magellan"]. When I use a PFQuery to lookup data, it does not execute the query. However, version two is not run in a for in loop nor does it use friend. It uses the actual string "magellan" instead and works fine. What is my problem?. Thanks

```
Version 1: 
override func viewdidload() {
for i in 0..<friendsArray.count {
    friend = friendsArray[i]
    print(friend)
    let query2 = PFQuery(className: "CheckPost")
               query2.whereKey("Username", equalTo: friend)
               query2.findObjectsInBackground  (block: { (objects:[PFObject]?, error: Error?) in
                   if let objects = objects {
                       for object in objects {
                           self.checkArray.append(object["Checks"] as! String)
                           self.checkArrayobjectId.append(object.objectId!);
                           self.checkTimeArray.append(object["UserTime"] as! String)
                           //append userimage
                           self.checkPicArray.append(UIImage(named: "randomguy")!)
                           print("successfully checked for friends checks")

                       }
                   } else if error != nil {
                       print(error)
                   }
               })
    }
Version 2: 
override func viewdidload()
for i in 0..<friendsArray.count {
    friend = friendsArray[i]
    print(friend)

    }
 let query2 = PFQuery(className: "CheckPost")
               query2.whereKey("Username", equalTo: "magellan")
               query2.findObjectsInBackground  (block: { (objects:[PFObject]?, error: Error?) in
                   if let objects = objects {
                       for object in objects {
                           self.checkArray.append(object["Checks"] as! String)
                           self.checkArrayobjectId.append(object.objectId!);
                           self.checkTimeArray.append(object["UserTime"] as! String)
                           //append userimage
                           self.checkPicArray.append(UIImage(named: "randomguy")!)
                           print("successfully checked for friends checks")

                       }
                   } else if error != nil {
                       print(error)
                   }
               })
         }
```

Comment: both versions print friend: ["magellan"]

Comment: you shodl restructure your query so you're not looping through and running a query for each loop interation. you can do this by searching the user tables for the obejcts in the friends array that match the value of the user name. when you return all objects that match, then do you looping and then add them to another array for a full PFObject saveAllInBackGround. looping like you're doing is not the preferred method and adds too much overhead with side effects.

Comment: It is not clear what is contained in the friendsArray. Are the PFObjects or an array of strings?  If the array contains objects then you will need to use dot notation or keys to extract the username value from the array element - this would explain why your second script "semi" works.

Comment: it contains strings

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are misunderstanding the async behavior of the `findObjectInBackground` function. This function is async and the callbacks will only be called after the loop has ended. You code should work with the `find` though. Something like this:

```
for i in 0..<friendsArray.count {
    friend = friendsArray[i]
    print(friend)
    let query2 = PFQuery(className: "CheckPost")
    query2.whereKey("Username", equalTo: friend)
    let objects = query2.find()
    if objects {
        for object in objects {
            self.checkArray.append(object["Checks"] as! String)
            self.checkArrayobjectId.append(object.objectId!);
            self.checkTimeArray.append(object["UserTime"] as! String)
            //append userimage
            self.checkPicArray.append(UIImage(named: "randomguy")!)
            print("successfully checked for friends checks")
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it has two errors: 1) Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled 2) [PFObject]' is not convertible to 'Bool'; and you need to update .find to .findobjects

Comment: You should consider iterating over the array directly - try not to use indexes. eg: [for friend in friendsArray {..]

Comment: agreed i have changed it to do this.